# Using an alias for Model in asp.net Razor

Tags: razor

Given the model used in my view of: @model Navigation

Is it possible to use an alias so that my code: @Model.MyNameField can become @Navigation.MyNameField?

This is purely for readability. I'd also be curious about why is would be bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the `Model` name is because that's the name of the property of the View class. If you subclass `View` and add a new property, it should work.

E.g.

```
public NavigationModel Navigation {
    Get { return Model.Navigation; }
}
```

You can then do `@Navigation.Foo`